# What distinguishes "cultural practices" from "applied Islam"?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I'm finding it hard to identify the boundary between "cultural practices" and, for lack of a better term, "applied Islam".

**Question**: What distinguishes "cultural practices" with "applied Islam"?

The distinction is important, because cultural practices are [off topic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> The following, however, are considered off-topic here except where
> they're shown to be directly relevant to the religion of Islam:
>
> - Cultural practices and behaviour of Muslim communities ...

while, as far as I can tell, asking questions about how one applies Islamic teachings to one's life is on topic.  Likewise, how communities as a whole apply Islamic teachings also seems on topic.

*Complication 1*: Many cultural practices in Islamic communities exist because they are believed to be part of Islam.  A cultural boundary may exist based on an Islamic sect, and questions about sects are on topic.

*Complication 2*: Difference in scholarly opinion means that what's cultural practice to one scholar, could be part of Islamic teachings to another scholar.

*Complication 3*:  It can be difficult to distinguish between:

- a group of Muslims do X, and X is allowed in Islam ("applied Islam"),
- a group of Muslims do X, but X is *not* allowed in Islam ("cultural practices"),
- a group of Muslims does *not* do X, but X is allowed in Islam ("cultural practices"), and
- a group of Muslims does *not* do X, and X is *not* allowed in Islam ("applied Islam").

This makes it difficult to ask about X.

*Complication 4*:  There's fatawa on cultural practices.

*Complication 5*:  It is beneficial to learn not only about "theoretical Islam" but how it actually exists in the real world, even though it differs from place to place.

Comment: related: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/350/22 http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/656/22

Comment: "What distinguishes “cultural practices” from “applied Islam”?" - whether the practice has a valid foundation in authoritative texts.